# Ethernet is turning off

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I have an Ubuntu 22.04. I use Ethernet cable. Same ethernet cable works ok on Windows and cables from same network work ok on other Windows PCs. But it seems like on my Ubuntu it is turning off, after working for some time, and then again starts working. I don't know what might be the problem, I already installed `neplan.io` since I saw it helped someone, but didn't help me, it keeps turning off sometimes. Here's output of `lshw -c network`:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 05
       serial: 74:56:3c:5a:b1:96
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.2.0-35-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 ip=192.168.0.111 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:43200000-4320ffff memory:43210000-43213fff
```

Here's output of `network-test`:

```
INFO: This system has exactly one default route
INFO: Host localhost answers to ICMP pings
INFO: Loopback interface is working properly
INFO: The enp3s0 interface is up
INFO: The enp3s0 interface has IP address 192.168.0.111 assigned
INFO: The enp3s0 interface has tx and rx packets.
WARN: The docker0 interface is down
WARN: The br-40e593db382e interface is down
WARN: The br-5653b8f2b366 interface is down
INFO: The router 192.168.0.1 is reachable
INFO: This system is configured to use nameserver 127.0.0.53
INFO: Host 127.0.0.53 answers to ICMP pings
INFO: Dns server 127.0.0.53 resolved correctly www.debian.org
INFO: The nameserver configured for this system works properly
INFO: System can reach Internet host www.debian.org
INFO: System can access web server at Internet host www.debian.org (port 80)
```

I can provide more info if you tell me what to run in the terminal.